What is the relationship between universal/existential quantification and modal necessity/possibility?
Is there a relationship between these two claims such that one entails the other?

∀p(p → K(p))
□(p → K(p))

And these two:

∃p(p → K(p))
◊(p → K(p))


None. First sentence in each pair is nonsensical in first order logic, one cannot quantify over propositions there. And in second order logic p is a dummy variable that can be replaced by any other, so they have nothing to do with p → q. What you should do instead is make p and q depend on a possible world w and quantify over those. Then ∀w(p(w) → q(w)) = □(p → q) and ∃w(p(w) → q(w)) = ◊(p → q) in possible world semantics.

Well there's Fitch's paradox that argues that ∀p(p → ◊Kp) ⊢ ∀p(p → Kp). So where q ≔ Kp it's saying ∀p(p → ◊q) ⊢ ∀p(p → q), which although undesirable is at least taken to be meaningful?

I assume the use of q rather than Kp makes a difference, so I've edited my question to be more specific.

Fitch's paradox is about arbitrary p, you instead have fixed p and q in your modal claims, so it does not help you.

Gotcha, I thought perhaps it was that. I read this and was confused about the way it described the relationship between modal logic and those quantifiers.
